# Copy & Paste Special as Values

Tags: python, openpyxl

Is copying a range of cells and pasting their value possible using `openpyxl`?

When accessing a cell for example we get this: `ws['D17'].value`, and the output is `u'=IFERROR(A15/A11,0)'`. How would I access the actual numerical value of the cell?

Edit: I can't load it using `data_only` since this is a template and formulas should remain intact to calculate certain values.

Comment: You can use `data_only` just as long as you don't save the file with the same nam. Maybe combine it with `read_only` so this isn't possible.

Comment: yea that's what I figure i'll do, thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Load the notebook with the `data_only` indicator argument:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
```

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned I need the formulas intact since I am writing out to a template which will calculate values. I could just have the person using my script open it afterwards and manually copy and paste as values to hide formulas but I thought I would save them a step.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy you can open two workbooks - one for formulas and one for pulling calculated values. As I noted before editing my answer, calculating the values by yourself (which is the only other option) would require great amount of work for you to create an excel formulas evaluator.

Comment: So you're saying insert my data into the template then save it. Then open that very same file in data only mode and copy that given range in to another work sheet? Seems time consuming given that there are all sorts of styles and charts and fancy doo-hickies that I would have to account for.